# Formatting timestamp ntz in Snowflow to output as date time YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MMZ

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-format, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

I have TIMESTAMP NTZ field in Snowflake. I need to output the value of the column in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MMZ
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
SELECT to_timestamp_tz(MAX("UPDATED_AT"), 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MMZ') FROM HISTORY;
```

Comment: You cannot do it in that format. See supported formats [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date-and-time-formats)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `timestamp_ntz` field that you want to represent in a specific way then you can use the [to_char](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html#to-char-to-varchar) function like this (assuming you want 24hr time):

```sql
SELECT
    to_char(MAX("UPDATED_AT"), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MIZ')
FROM HISTORY;
```

Complete example:

```sql
create or replace temporary table test_table
(
    id number,
    ts timestamp_ntz
);

insert overwrite into test_table
values (1, '2021-04-13T01:00:00'::timestamp_ntz),
       (2, '2021-04-14T01:00:00'::timestamp_ntz)
;

select
    id,
    to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MIZ')
from test_table
;
```

The above produces:

```
+--+----------------------------------+
|ID|TO_CHAR(TS, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MIZ')|
+--+----------------------------------+
|1 |2021-04-13T01:00Z                 |
|2 |2021-04-14T01:00Z                 |
+--+----------------------------------+
```